# Как изменить, пересчитать хэш пакета и отправить его в порт в модуле linux?

Tags: linux, kernel, модули

```
#define __KERNEL__
#define MODULE
    #include <linux/kernel.h>
    #include <linux/module.h>
    #include <linux/netfilter.h>
    #include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
    #include <linux/skbuff.h>
    #include <linux/udp.h>
    #include <linux/ip.h>
    #include <net/ip.h>
    #include <linux/inet.h>
static struct nf_hook_ops netfilter_ops_in; /* NF_IP_PRE_ROUTING */
static struct nf_hook_ops netfilter_ops_out; /* NF_IP_POST_ROUTING */
/* Function prototype in <linux/netfilter> */
unsigned int main_hook(unsigned int hooknum,  
                  struct sk_buff *skb,
                  const struct net_device *in,
                  const struct net_device *out,
                  int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff*))
{
struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);

if (htonl (in_aton("192.168.0.1")) == htonl(iph->saddr)){
**printk(KERN_ALERT "поймал пакет  \n");** ---- тут условие, по которому я ловлю пакеты

}
return NF_ACCEPT; /* Allow ALL Packets */
}
int init_module()
{
        netfilter_ops_in.hook                   =       main_hook;
        netfilter_ops_in.pf                     =       PF_INET;
        netfilter_ops_in.hooknum                =       0;
        netfilter_ops_in.priority               =       NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;
        netfilter_ops_out.hook                  =       main_hook;
        netfilter_ops_out.pf                    =       PF_INET;
        netfilter_ops_out.hooknum               =       4;
        netfilter_ops_out.priority              =       NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;
        nf_register_hook(&netfilter_ops_in); /* register NF_IP_PRE_ROUTING hook */
        nf_register_hook(&netfilter_ops_out); /* register NF_IP_POST_ROUTING hook */
return 0;
}
void cleanup_module()
{
nf_unregister_hook(&netfilter_ops_in); /*unregister NF_IP_PRE_ROUTING hook*/
nf_unregister_hook(&netfilter_ops_out); /*unregister NF_IP_POST_ROUTING hook*/
}
```

Подскажите, какими мне методами изменить адрес назначения пакета, пересчитать хэш и отправить его в порт?

Comment: в ответе есть пример: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8237983/4827341

Comment: Большое спасибо! Помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/in.h>


static uint16_t csum(uint16_t* buff, int nwords) {
    uint32_t sum;
    for (sum = 0; nwords > 0; nwords--)
            sum += *buff++;
    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
    sum += (sum >> 16);

    return ((uint16_t) ~sum);
}

printk(KERN_ALERT "INFO: Source IP Address: %pI4.\n",&iph->saddr);
printk(KERN_ALERT "INFO: Destination IP Address: %pI4.\n",&iph->daddr);
printk("src mac %pM, dst mac %pM\n", eth->h_source, eth->h_dest);
printk(KERN_ALERT "INFO: CHECKSUM: %u.\n",&iph->check);//выводим хэш сумму прибившего пакета
iph->check = 0;// необходимо обнулить предыдущую хэш сумму
iph->daddr = in_aton("192.168.137.1");                                                                                                       
iph->check = csum((uint16_t*) iph, (iph->ihl << 1));    //вычисляем хэш 
printk(KERN_ALERT "INFO: CHECKSUM: %u.\n",&iph->check); //выводим новую хэш сумму
```

Спасибо за ссылку @alexander-barakin https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178576/alexander-barakin